# Plural of "first child"

Tags: grammatical-number

If multiple people each have a first child, are those children collectively referred to as *first children* or *first childs*? The former seems more consistent with the usual plural of *child*, but the latter also seems plausible, since a given person only has a single first child.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the plural of 'only child'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204027/what-is-the-plural-of-only-child)

Comment: Analogous to [Mari-Lou A's comment.answer there](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204027/what-is-the-plural-of-only-child#comment431515_204027), I'd say _first children_ is correct, but confusing - you could use **firstborn**. Can't find a quick reference (ODO mentions it as a noun, but names no plural) but I have the feeling it can be used _unchanged_ as a plural: Twelve families with their firstborn. You could always opt for the less archaic adjective form: Twelve families and their firstborn children.

Comment: What if the first children you have are twins? And what if they're both bald but for one hair each and you take them to get a haircut? What do you ask the barber?

Comment: @Mitch Even if the twins/etc are delivered via CSection instead of naturally, they're removed one at a time.  The 1st one out is the firstborn, if only by a minute or three.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of the one mentioned by @DanBron because the answer isn't *first children*, but rather *firstborns* or *firstborn children*. The expression *firstborn is nowhere to be seen in either of the two questions, and I see very little connection with the meaning of "only child". **Firstborn** means the eldest child/sibling.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A first child is commonly called *firstborn*; therefore I'd venture to say that the plural form is *firstborn children*.

> The one thing you can bet your paycheck on is the **firstborn** and
>   **second-born** in any given family are going to be different," says Dr.
>   Kevin Leman, a psychologist who has studied birth order since 1967 and
>   author of The Birth Order Book: Why You Are the Way You Are (Revell).
>   (...)
>   Psychologists like Leman believe the secret to sibling personality
>   differences lies in birth order -- whether **you're a first-, middle-,
>   last-born, or only child** -- and how parents treat their child because
>   of it.

However, the same article uses the plural term *firstborns*. In fact typing the term in Google books receives [36,300 results](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=firstborns)

> **Firstborns** bask in their parents' presence, which may explain why they
>   sometimes act like mini-adults. **Firstborns** are diligent and want to be
>   the best at everything they do. They excel at winning the hearts of
>   their elders.

<sup>http://www.parents.com/baby/development/social/birth-order-and-personality/</sup>

While *firstborn children* (two words) gets [16,100 hits](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22firstborn%20children%22)

> **Firstborn children really do excel, reveals groundbreaking study**
>   What do Angela Merkel, Hillary Clinton, Christine Lagarde, Oprah Winfrey, Sheryl Sandberg, JK Rowling and Beyoncé have in common? Other than riding high in Forbes list of the world's most powerful women, they are also all firstborn children in their families.

<sup>[The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/society/2014/apr/26/firstborn-children-excel-study-reveals)</sup>

Finally, it can also be written with the hyphen, *first-born children*. Google Books produces a healthier [390,000 results](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22first-born%20children%22)

EDIT

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=firstborns%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cfirstborns%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cfirstborn%20children%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cfirstborn%20children%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfirstborns%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfirstborns%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfirstborn%20children%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfirstborn%20children%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfirstborns%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cfirstborns%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cfirstborn%20children%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cfirstborn%20children%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc1) suggests that between the mid-1960s and 70s the plural form, *firstborns*, has taken over *firstborn children* and is far more common in the US (red) than in the UK (blue), which I confess I found a little surprising.

[image: Google Ngram chart plotting AmEng firstborns and firstborn children vs. BrEng firstb]

Comment: Your comment on the other question inspired my comment on this one! Do you concur that _firstborn_ used as a noun can be treated as a mass-noun? Or would you simply advice against using it as a noun?

Comment: @Orkelens: the biblical *"plague of the firstborn"* certainly uses *firstborn* as a plural. It's not a mass noun because you would say *"the firstborn were"* and not *"the firstborn was"* when you're using it to refer to two or more firstborn children. It's an adjective, and you don't usually add *s* to adjectives when they are used as nouns — *"only the good die young"*.

Comment: You can also use the plural form, firstborns. Sorry, for the delay but my computer is sooo slow today :(