# Would "lady-lover" be hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation

When used to mean "someone who loves ladies", rather than a female lover.

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lady+lover%2Clady-lover&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clady%20lover%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clady%20-%20lover%3B%2Cc0) demonstrates that the non-hyphenated variety is in more common use.

Comment: @Nigel The Ngram doesn't distinguish usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That thought also occurred to me, but when I considered the alternatives, they were so unlikely that I felt they would not be significant data. Point taken, though.

Comment: I can see why you feel the need to rule out the attributive usage, which would default to 'a lover who is a lady'. Hyphenation is the standard way to disambiguate hereabouts (a sweet-shop girl vs a sweet shop-girl). But I'd be tempted to rephrase here; neither string is really a standard compound / collocation, and there is a slang sense for 'lady lover'.

Comment: There are expressions available which are more idiomatic.

Comment: Related: [Child-murderer or child murderer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253644)

Comment: Doesn't the Question give itself away? "someone who loves ladies" is not *opposed to* "a female lover". All that happened there was, both avoided the Question.